# Is it possible to create recovery CDs/DVDs from a recovery partition?

Tags: disaster-recovery

I recently acquired a HP laptop that has no recovery CDs or DVDs nor is there any software that will allow me to create them on the laptop. Furthermore is the laptop is infested with every imaginable virus and trojan.

The laptop does however have a recovery partition. How can I create the recovery CDs or DVDs from the recovery partition?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to reinstall Windows on the laptop? I would reinstall with an appropriate new copy of Windows if the system is as damaged as you indicate. I typically never bother with the recovery partition. Drivers for the laptop can be acquired at the [manufacturer's support page](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/support-drivers.html).

Since you mention HP, there is a [procedure to recover from the recovery partition](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=uk&docname=bph07143).

From HP.com:

*You may not need to have recovery discs to perform a System Recovery. The recovery information is contained on a partition on the hard drive. Recovery discs are necessary in case the recovery partition is not functioning properly. If your computer originally came with Windows 7 or Vista, turn on the computer and repeatedly press F11 to access the recovery information on the hard drive. If your computer originally came with Windows XP or earlier, press F10 to enter recovery.*

Comment: Since he said it is infested, that would assume that nothing has been done to the boot sector, or has been root-kitted. There is the off chance that he may need to even do a low-level format (I once did a standard reformat and install only to have the virus come back) to get rid of the worst viruses so it still helps to have the disks made anyway. He can still try the F11 way first, and I would too.

Comment: Thanks. That's a good started however as KCotreau I may have to go down the low-level format. In that case, how would I be able to create the recovery CDs/DVDs? Would I create them once I re-install the operating system via F11? If I do so, will the recovery CDs/DVDs be infected?

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is in something like Start>All Programs>Hewlett-Packard>HP PC Recovery CD Creator, or try clicking PC Help & Tools then HP CD Recovery CD-DVD Creator to start the program. It depends on the specific PC model.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such software installed.

Comment: What specific model is it?